# Matlab error when playing a sound

Tags: matlab, user-interface, audio, error-handling

I'm using matlab gui, I'm recording a sound then save it in a folder in c, then display the recorded sound that are in the folder in a listbox when I press play on the sound wav. Matlab gives an error the error is :

```
************Error using audioread (line 74)**
***The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path.
Error in Monitoring_System>play_Callback (line 178)
[q, Fs] = audioread(thisstring);
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in Monitoring_System (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in @(hObject,eventdata)Monitoring_System('play_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback*************
```

-The record code:

```
format shortg
             c = clock;
             fix(c);
             a=num2str(c);
             year=strcat(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5));
             month=strcat(a(19),a(20));
             day=strcat(a(33),a(34));
             hour=strcat(a(48),a(49));
             min=strcat(a(63),a(64));
             sec=strcat(a(74),a(75));
             name=strcat(year,'-',month,'-',day,'-',hour,'-',min,'-',sec);
             fullpath=fullfile('c:\monitoringsystem',name);
             wavwrite(y,44100,fullpath);
             y=[];
```

The code to diplay them in the listbox:

```
d = dir('C:\monitoringsystem\*.wav'); %get files


set(handles.listbox1,'String',{d.name})
```

The code to play the sound that is chosen from the listbox:

```
allstrings = cellstr( get(handles.listbox1, 'String') );
curvalue = get(handles.listbox1, 'Value');
thisstring = allstrings{curvalue};
[q, Fs] = audioread(thisstring);
 soundsc(q,44100);
```

Any help how to solve this problem, with keeping to save in a specific folder. I copied the recorded sound to the matlab folder and then pressed play in the gui for that wav sound it didin't give any error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging this and seeing what `d` contains after selecting a file?

[As per the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), `d = dir('C:\monitoringsystem\*.wav');` returns a `struct` with the following fields: `name`, `date`,`bytes`, `isdir`, `datenum` (at least on MATLAB 2015a). Although `{d.name}` gives you the filename correctly, you should note that this is a **relative path** only, so MATLAB doesn't where to look for the file unless it's in the active directory.

I'm not entirely sure why you went through all the trouble with `allstrings`, `curvalue`, and `thisstring`, but if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I would suggest one of two approaches:

1. Define the default path (i.e. `C:\monitoringsystem`) in a constant, and then use it when saving\loading:

   ```
   DEFAULT_PATH = `C:\monitoringsystem`; %// Definition
   ...
   fullpath = fullfile(DEFAULT_PATH,name); %// When saving
   ...
   d = dir(fullfile(DEFAULT_PATH,'*.wav')); %// When listing files
   ...
   [q, Fs] = audioread(fullfile(DEFAULT_PATH,{d.name})); %// When reading a file
   ```
2. Using [uigetfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html):

   ```
   [FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.wav','Select the WAV file');
   FullPath = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
   ```

   (and then the rest is very similar to the 1st case)